# How to control bluetooth operations using adb shell?

Tags: android, shell, bluetooth, adb

I am working on automating bluetooth actions on android like enable/disable, pairing/unpairing devices etc.

I want to know how to interact with unrooted android device for above mentioned bluetooth operations using adb shell commands or android intents.

For example, i want to know which devices are bluetooth paired with my android phone using adb shell commands.

is it possible?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/37259260/1778421

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51050395/find-connected-bluetooth-device-name-using-adb

Answer (score 0):

dumpsys is your friend:

- Find your bluetooth service (must be running): `adb shell dumpsys -l`
- Mine is bluetooth_manager, so I run: `adb shell dumpsys bluetooth_manager`
- In output you can find section "Bonded devices"

Comment: how would you use this command's output in order to invoke bluetooth-related operations, such as pair or unpair to another device?

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.