# android enable disable bluetooth via command line

Tags: shell, terminal, bluetooth, command, adb

I am trying to enable disable bluetooth on android device using command line.

I can enable it using

`adb shell am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE`

But it prompts user to 'allow' or 'deny'.

I also see there is option to launch ble settings first like

`adb shell am start -a android.settings.BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS`

and then enable disable `adb shell input keyevent **`

But it won't be device independent.

Comment: Were you able to find how to handle the prompt with adb ?

Answer (score 27):

**Updated**: 2023-03-10 - *Android 12/13*

### Enable bluetooth via `cmd`

```
adb shell cmd bluetooth_manager enable
```

### Disable bluetooth `cmd`

```
adb shell cmd bluetooth_manager disable
```

---

**Updated**: 2019-06-22: - *Android 11*

### Print current bluetooth status via `settings`

```
adb shell settings get global bluetooth_on 
adb shell settings list global |grep ^bluetooth_on
```

### Enable Bluetooth via `settings`

```
adb shell settings put global bluetooth_disabled_profiles 1
```

### Disable bluetooth `settings`

```
adb shell settings put global bluetooth_disabled_profiles 0
```

---

### Enable bluetooth via `content`

```
adb shell content insert \
  --uri content://settings/global \
  --bind name:s:bluetooth_disabled_profiles \
  --bind value:s:1 --user 0
```

### Disable bluetooth `content`

```
adb shell content insert \
  --uri content://settings/global \
  --bind name:s:bluetooth_disabled_profiles \
  --bind value:s:0 --user 0
```

---

*Android 11/12/13 and older versions*

### Enable Bluetooth

```
adb shell settings put global bluetooth_on 1
```

### Disable Bluetooth

```
adb shell settings put global bluetooth_on 0
```

---

### Enable bluetooth via `activity manager`

```
adb shell am broadcast \
  -a android.intent.action.BLUETOOTH_ENABLE --ez state true
```

### Disable bluetooth via `activity manager`

```
adb shell am broadcast \
  -a android.intent.action.BLUETOOTH_ENABLE --ez state false
```

---

### Enable/Disable bluetooth via `keyevents`

```
adb shell am start \
  -a android.settings.BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS  \
  adb shell input keyevent 19
  adb shell input keyevent 23
```

Comment: On Huawei P30 Pro with Android P even your new solution doesn't work. When I use `adb shell settings put global bluetooth_disabled_profiles 1`, it **disables** bluetooth (as opposite to what you say) and `adb shell settings put global bluetooth_disabled_profiles 0` does nothing, it doesn't enable nor disable it.

Comment: See if they have changed the name so it might be bluetooth_on instead of bluetooth_disabled_profiles. If you type 'adb shell settings  list global|grep -i bluetooth'  you should get some alternatives what you can try if above dosn't work so just change name and value if needed, above works fine on Huawei P9, Samsung S8 and Huawei P8 that's all I have tried on with Android 8.0 & Android 9.0. Regards

Comment: For reference, `adb shell settings put global bluetooth_on 1` worked on a Samsung S7

Comment: for me, all of these methods from 2019 edit (both disable and enable) disable bluetooth for just a very quick amount of time. It rather looks like a reset. Samsung A50, Android 10 (kernel 4.14 )

Comment: `adb shell settings put global bluetooth_on 0` worked for me in android 12.1 - but is there anyway that I can make it non-persistent so that behavior is same after each boot?

When `settings put global bluetooth_on 0` - it retains the value and next time I reboot, I notice that boot_completed never gets set to 1. Unless I wipe /data partition and restart again and re-put `settings put global bluetooth_on 0`.

Answer (score 20):

To enable:

```
adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 6
```

To disable:

```
adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 8
```

Comment: Both commands did not work for me. I am using Samsung S4 device and its Android 4.2.

Comment: We are trying to enable and disable Bluetooth before we start our automation test using adb commands
Enable

    adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 6

Disable

    adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 9

We are getting the Bluetooth status using this command

    adb shell settings get global bluetooth_on

Are there any other work around to enable and disable the bluetooth using APPIUM java because these commands working in some devices but not in all the device.  Any solution for this?

The same commands working in Android 5 (Lollipop)

Comment: using static method codes as suggested here will never work across all devices. These codes can and do change on a per device basis depending on vendor and OEM modifications.

Comment: Is there a document specifying what 6 and 8 state means?

Comment: this worked for Moto E4 on Android v7.1.1 - but only with root:
`adb shell su -c "service call bluetooth_manager 8"`

Answer (score 12):

To enable

```
svc bluetooth enable
```

To disable

```
svc bluetooth disable
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for Android 12 Moto G22

Comment: Thank you this worked for me on Android 12.

Answer (score 5):

For folks who are wondering from where did the numbers 6 and 8 came from. It came from this aidl file: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/master/binder/android/bluetooth/IBluetoothManager.aidl
Start counting from the first function listed in this aidl and you will see the enable function is the 6th one and the disable is the 8th one in the list.

Answer (score 5):

This might be a bit of a hacky solution but once you try to enable or disable bluetooth, you can use the right key action followed by the enter key action to select the allow button which is usually on the very right.

This should work even if your device is not rooted.

To enable:

```
adb shell am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE
adb shell input keyevent 22 (right)
adb shell input keyevent 22 (right)
adb shell input keyevent 66 (enter)
```

To disable:

```
adb shell am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISABLE
adb shell input keyevent 22 (right)
adb shell input keyevent 22 (right)
adb shell input keyevent 66 (enter)
```

Answer (score 3):

To run commands listed in previous comment, you need to be root:

`adb root`

Enable:

`adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 6`

Disable:

`adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 8`

Comment: When I run this command I get a strange output (similar to what xxd produces) that has the message

`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.AttributionSource.getPackageName(' on a ull object reference.d,..at com.android.server.BluetoothManagerService.enableNoAutoConnect(BluetoothManagerService.java:1136)..at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothManager$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothManager.java:294)..at ndroid.os.Binder.execTransactInterval(Binder.java:1184)..at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1143)...`

Answer (score 3):

To enable:

```
adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 6
```

To disable:

```
adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 9
```

Tested and worked on a Samsung Galaxy S7.

Answer (score 3):

As awm129 has pointed out, solutions using `service call` aren't device-independent. While I am unable to completely eliminate the use of `service call`, the following solution should be more device-independent:

To disable:

```
pm disable com.android.bluetooth
```

To enable:

```
pm enable com.android.bluetooth
service call bluetooth_manager 6
```

I hope someone will eventually find a `service call`-free solution.

Answer (score 1):

On Xiaomi Mi 4i / MIUI 9:

To enable:

> adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 8

To disable:

> adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 10

This can also run within Andorid like:

> service call bluetooth_manager 10

Comment: Poco F1 / MIUI 10.2 / Pie: 5 to enable, 8 to disable

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use  `settings put`, `svc`, and `actions`.

It works for **all Android versions** and **all devices**.

```
val isOn =true

val command = "adb shell settings put global bluetooth_on ${
    if (isOn) {
        "1"
    } else {
        "0"
    }
} && adb shell svc bluetooth ${
    if (isOn) {
        "enable"
    } else {
        "disable"
    }
} && adb shell am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.${
    if (isOn) {
        "REQUEST_ENABLE"
    } else {
        "REQUEST_DISABLE"
    }
} && adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BLUETOOTH_ENABLE --ez state $isOn"
```