# How to using adb command to test bluetooth on Android 7?

Tags: android, command-line, bluetooth, adb

We are using Android 7 on development, but our board did't have display output.
Did android 7 provide commands for enable/disable bluetooth, scanning the devices, I can pair my board with other bluetooth device from command line. Thanks.

Comment: this better answer for all versions https://stackoverflow.com/a/72084922/4797289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For enable disable bluetooth can use

to enbale

```
adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 6
```

to disable

```
adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 8
```

to view paired BT device

```
adb shell dumpsys bluetooth_manager
```