# ADB shell bluetooth commands

Tags: android, shell, bluetooth, adb

I'm currently looking into automating testing of a bluetooth connection between an android phone and another device.

I've found many useful ADB commands such as

- `adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 6`
- `adb shell am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE`
- `adb shell am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE`
- `adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 8`

but could not find anything for the following actions:

- Scan for discoverable bluetooth devices
- Pair with a given discovered bluetooth device
- Forget earlier paired bluetooth device
- Connect with earlier paired bluetooth device
- Disconnect with earlier paired bluetooth device

Do these exist? Or do I need to write a wrapper Android app that can perform these actions?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Comment: let's keep these two together http://stackoverflow.com/q/25658407/1778421