# ADB: How to automate complete BT Scan, pair and connect

Tags: android, adb, android-bluetooth, android-debug, android-shell

I am looking for Automating the below activities using ADB.

Bluetooth settings -> TunrnOn BT -> Pairing (To a BT mac address which i can set) -> Connect to the BT Device on certain profiles like A2DP/HFP.

I have already found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658407/how-to-control-bluetooth-operations-using-adb-shell?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259260/android-enable-disable-bluetooth-via-command-line?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) how to turn on and set BT to discoverable using ADB. But I am still stuck on how to make a connection request again using ADB.

Would there be a way to completely automate these steps.

Appreciate your valuable comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no solution possible only using ADB. 
But there still is a possibility using ui automator. 
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator