# Connect a paired bluetooth device via terminal on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, adb

I need to connect a paired bluetooth devices via the terminal, when it does not connect automatically.

On my Android 7.1 device I would normally click the bluetooth device to connect it, in bluetooth settings. Unfortunately, I do not have a touchscreen or mouse in my setup. So I'd like to use the terminal to connect it. For specific reasons I do want to do this from the Android device, not from a connected PC etc.

I only found a way to enable and disable bluetooth via adb (`adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 8`). As mentioned I do not want to use adb, but I want to connect from my Android device. Is it also possible to connect to paired devices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADB: How to automate complete BT Scan, pair and connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50271696/adb-how-to-automate-complete-bt-scan-pair-and-connect)

Comment: `adb shell dumpsys bluetooth_manager` would list the bonded devices.

Comment: If your requirement is control android device without a display, you can use `vysor` or `android screen monitor` to control using your PC connected.