# Find connected bluetooth device name using adb?

Tags: android, shell, adb, tasker

Is there any way to find the connected **BT device name** using adb shell?

My phone is *rooted* and I'm building a tasker profile which flashes the BT device name when connected.

Answer (score 4):

You want to know your Bluetooth profile name or connected/paired device bluetooth name?

Both names you can get by below command:

```
adb shell dumpsys bluetooth_manager
```

The above command will give the output like this:

```
Bluetooth Status
  enabled: true
  state: STATE_ON
  address: A4:70:D6:80:56:3E
  name: Moto G (4) (This is your device name)
  time since enabled: 00:03:29.979

Bonded devices:
  C0:EE:FB:DA:70:6E [BR/EDR] Oneplus3 (This is connected device name)
  ...................................
  ...................................
```

Comment: i want the name of the connected device only. bonded devices list is showing multiple BT devices, is the first one always the connected one? also could you  provide a way to parse this dump to get just the name of the connected BTdevice. Thanks.

Comment: The list of `Bonded devices` are devices paired with the android device that you're querying.
You can filter your results to just the name of the android device that you're querying by using `adb shell "dumpsys bluetooth_manager | grep name:"`