# Is there a way to get the device name using adb? For example, if the device name is John Doe's Nexus, how to get the name using a command?

Tags: android, adb, device-name

I have an android device, which when registered to an account renames itself after the account name. I need to get that name using adb.

Comment: Can you retrieve what you want with the `adb devices` command?

Comment: adb devices retrieves the serial number but I want to get the user friendly name. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
adb shell dumpsys bluetooth_manager
```

See full answer here: [Find connected bluetooth device name using adb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51050395/find-connected-bluetooth-device-name-using-adb)

Comment: From Mac OS X, I use this to print only the device name:
`adb shell dumpsys bluetooth_manager | \grep 'name:' | cut -c9-`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
./adb shell getprop
```

It returns all device properties which should also contain the name that you are looking for. I got multiple name properties:

```
[ro.product.name]: [TA-1032_00WW]
[ro.product.nickname]: [Nokia 3]
[ro.vendor.product.name]: [NE1_00WW_FIH]
```

I think you are looking for ro.product.nickname. You can get it with this command on Mac/Linux:

```
./adb shell getprop | grep "ro.product.nickname"
```

The Windows command should be similar. Something like this:

```
adb shell 
getprop | grep -e 'ro.product.nickname'
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but I am not looking for the nickname but the user friendly name that can be set by the user himself.

Comment: 'ro.boot.qemu.avd_name' was the key that ended up working for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `adb devices -l` argument there to get the info and the you can just filter the output to obtain the model ej:

```
❯ adb devices -l
List of devices attached
16fb60660205           device usb:1245184X product:daisy model:Mi_A2_Lite device:daisy_sprout transport_id:7
9A101FFBA003K4         device usb:1179648X product:coral model:Pixel_4_XL device:coral transport_id:8
```